# How to Use Procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

Help me fix error create PROCEDURE, thank you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Login(IN AuserName VARCHAR(100),IN ApassWork VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Account 
    WHERE UserName = AuserName AND PassWord = ApassWork;
END;
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a ; in the middle of your procedure as well, change delimiter for just creating the procedure as this and change it again.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Login(IN AuserName VARCHAR(100),IN ApassWork VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Account 
    WHERE UserName = AuserName AND PassWord = ApassWork;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it.

Comment: Correct answer well documented +1

Comment: @LýThànhTrung great :) May be this article(https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php) will help you learn more.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the mysql delimiter,since you have use delimiter ';' more than one place. Use the delimiter command as

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Login(IN AuserName VARCHAR(100),IN ApassWork VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Account 
    WHERE UserName = AuserName AND PASSWORD = ApassWork;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Please refer 
[Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

Comment: Correct answer well documented +1

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add DELIMITER // as it is MYSQL

```
DELIMITER //

 -- Procedure statment
//DELIMITER ;
```